# In which chapter of the quran is the invocation' there is no god but the God, and Muhammed is his prophet'?

Tags: quran

The basis of a Muslim's Imaan is the statement:

> There is no god but Allah, and Muhammed is his prophet.

Is this found anywhere in the Qur'an?

Comment: Hope the edit gives you an idea of designing questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I didn't know it was called Imaan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: In the name of Allah, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful]

There could have been many examples, but this one will be enough Insha Allah.

> #### [Surat Al-'A`rāf :: Ayah 158](http://quran.com/7/158):
>
> Say, [O Muhammad], "O mankind, **indeed I am the Messenger of Allah to you all**, [from Him] to whom belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth. **There is no deity except Him**; He gives life and causes death." So believe in Allah and His Messenger, the unlettered prophet, who believes in Allah and His words, and follow him that you may be guided.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي